# Constraint on decision variable CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I have some network flow problem, where c[A] are the costs per arc of the network and x is the decision variable to define the amount distributed via which arc

```
range A = 1..100;
float c[A] = ...; // array of 100 floats from .dat file 

dvar x[A];


minimize sum (a in A) c[a] * x[a];

subject to{


}
```

I want to change a certain set if cost arcs depending on the decision variable.

Lets say: when the amount per arc is larger then 100, 10 % discount.

: `c[i] <= c[i]*0.9 other value, when  x[i] >= given value`. How to formulate this as a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

```
range A = 1..100;
float c[a in A] = a*2; 

dvar int x[A];


minimize sum (a in A) c[a] * x[a];

subject to{

forall(i in A:c[i]<=100) x[i] >= c[i]*0.9;
forall(i in A:c[i]>100) x[i] >= c[i];

}
```

works fine

```
range A = 1..100;
float c[a in A] = a*2; 

dvar int x[A];


minimize sum (a in A) c[a] * x[a];

subject to{

forall(i in A) (x[i]<=100) => (x[i] >= c[i]*0.9);
forall(i in A) (x[i]>=101) => (x[i] >= c[i]);

}
```

works fine too

```
range A = 1..100;
float c[a in A] = a*2; 

dvar int x[A];


minimize sum (a in A) c[a] * x[a];

subject to{

forall(i in A) (x[i] >= ((c[i]<=100)?c[i]:c[i]*0.9));


}
```

Comment: You are conditioning on the cost array < 100, I want to condition in the decision variable if x array < 100 then change c[i] to c[i]*0.9

Comment: You are saying that the `x[i] >= c[i]`, but that is not what I want, I want to change the `c[i]` like `c[i]` becomes `c[i]*` (`c[i]* ==c[i] *0.9`)

Comment: shouldnt it be: `forall(i in A) (x[i] >= ((x[i]<=100)?c[i]:c[i]*0.9));` but that gives the error: Decision variable (or expression) "x" not allowed.`